# How to change/edit the device id on AVD Android Studios

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, avd-manager

Isit it possible to change the device id/ device name on AVD android studios?

I am using Android studios on Windows if that helps you answer.

Image attached. I would like to test apps however many apps recognise the device by the device name.

Will be very helpful if someone can help

Comment: Please attach the image, which you mentioned.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.